# Optimizing training algorithm, Python

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, text-mining

So to start off I have a dict "trainDocs" which is of the form

```
{docId : docNode}
```

where the doc_container class is defined by:

```
class docNode:
    def __init__(self, document):
        self.doc_vec = document
        self.k_neighbors = []
```

where doc_vec is a tf-idf representation of the document, and k_neighbors is going to be a list of the k nearest neighbors (using euclidean distance). I defined a "train" method defined below:

```
def train(trainDocs): 
    train_Docs = {}
    for docId, processedDoc in trainDocs.items():       
        doc_container = docNode(doc_to_vec(docId, processedDoc)) 
        if train_Docs: 
            doc_container.k_neighbors = updateNeighbors(docId, doc_container, train_Docs) 
            train_Docs[docId] = doc_container
        else:
            train_Docs[docId] = doc_container
    return train_Docs
```

Where update neighbors is defined by :

```
def updateNeighbors(currId, currNode, trainDocs, k=5): 
    #k is number of neighbors
    currNode_neighbors = []
    for docId, docNode in trainDocs.items():
        dist = euclideanDist(currNode.doc_vec,docNode.doc_vec) 
        if len(currNode_neighbors) < k: 
            heapq_max.heappush_max(currNode_neighbors, (dist, docId))
        else:
            if currNode_neighbors[0][0] > dist: heapq_max.heapreplace_max(currNode_neighbors, (dist, docId))
        if len(docNode.k_neighbors) < k: 
            heapq_max.heappush_max(docNode.k_neighbors, (dist, currId)) 
        else: 
            if docNode.k_neighbors[0][0] > dist: heapq_max.heapreplace_max(docNode.k_neighbors, (dist, currId))
```

So the update neighbors method is O(n^2) because euclideanDist is a linear (in time) function. I decided to have it update neighbors as the script runs because less things to look through implies a faster runtime at first (it gets really slow as more docs are added). My question is if anyone can think of a way to optimize this so it doesn't take as long. Feel free to ask questions too.

P.S. doc_to_vec is a linear function

Comment: Are you using NumPy/SciPy to store the tf-idf vectors?

Comment: @SergeiLebedev No I am not, I am storing the tf-idf vectors in the docNode classes, and then creating a dict with {docId : docNode} and then I am using _pickle to store it externally so I don't have to recreate it various times.

Comment: Also the tf idf vectors are stored in dicts to avoid sparseness

Comment: I think it might be more efficient to store them in a sparse matrix from SciPy: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html